# Redraw canvas on android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have my custom view with canvas and draw bitmap.
Set canvas transparent and when I draw bitmap with transparent region, I can't see transparent regions. But, when I set some color of canvas, I can see this color.

```
snowflakesTriangle = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snowflakesTriangle, realBmpWidth,realBmpHeight, true);

SnowFlakeView surface = (SnowFlakeView)findViewById(R.id.snow_flake_view);
surface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
SurfaceHolder holder = surface.getHolder();
holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
canvas.drawARGB(0, 25, 67, 178);  
usersTriangle = getResizedBitmap(snowflakesTriangle, relativeBmpWidth, relativeBmpHeight);
canvas.drawBitmap(usersTriangle, marginForBmp, marginForBmp, null);  
drawPoints(canvas);  
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: pass a paint object instead of null and set Alpha to the paint object

Comment: but I need some parts of image - transperent, and some must be some color